# Pass database credentials as command line input in Quartz API with Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, properties, quartz-scheduler

I have a Spring Boot application having quartz API to create and schedule job triggers. To configure quartz scheduler I have quartz.properties where DB details including username and password are mentioned.

I want to pass username and password as command line parameters rather than using that from quartz.properties. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score -1):

You can use [QuartzAutoConfiguration](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/quartz/QuartzAutoConfiguration.java) if you are using `spring-boot >= 2.0.0`. For that you can annotate some `DataSource` with [QuartzDataSource](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/quartz/QuartzDataSource.html) for which you can specify your own spring properties. And then you can pass standard spring properties to your application.